# How can I call a method or update a label from the specified class to the specified class

Tags: c#

Let me elaborate on the scenario:

program.cs creates my_form.cs instance
my_form.cs creates network.cs class

from program.cs I can access my_form instance methods etc
from my_form.cs I can access network instance methods etc

from program.cs I can't access network.cs
from my_form.cs I can't access program.cs

my_form contains a label object with text property that I want to update when a method from network runs.

What I don't understand is if I can instantiate the class network.cs from my_form.cs and can thereby access network.cs methods/etc from my_form.cs, then why can't I pass the class my_form.cs reference/pointer to network.cs and access my_forms' methods.

or

ClassA
ClassB
ClassC

ClassA creates ClassB,ClassC

So A can access B and C, but B can't access A or C, and C can't access B and A..

So I'm told how can I access a class if I don't instantiate it, and so I'll instantiate one but I've already got an existing class, I don't want to create a second form ?

Code:

Form

```
network NetworkInst = new network();
 static void updateLblServerStatus(bool result)
        {

            lbl_status.text = result.tostring();
        }
```

network

```
Form.updateLblServerStatus(true); //no access
```

Access modifiers:

Form1 is non static public, method is public, label is public
network is non static public, method which tries to call Form1 method is public too.

Comment: "A can access B and C, but B can't access A or C"
Of course it can, if it has an instance of it. So you have to pass that instance to `B`, for example via constructor. Another approach: avoid that `B` has to access `C` directly, but use an event-driven approach. For example: the user selects something in `B` which raises an event, the controller `A` listens to that event and then updates `C`.

Comment: I agree with @TimSchmelter 's suggestion. See [MSDN's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=net-5.0).This exact scenario represents the first triumph I learned over my beginner 'hacky' programming patterns of making public static fields to allow shared instance access.

Comment: [Here's the project](https://github.com/bcwalnja/Scoreboard) I learned this pattern on. I created an `EventMediator` Singleton class that all the forms and controllers subscribed to and submitted events to.

Comment: I removed the "accessibility" tag as it doesn't seem related (it is a tag for making products accessible for people with disabilities), if this is related to accessibility and I have missed something in the question feel free to re-add it.